# Overriding a dependency in a Micronaut test

Tags: java, dependency-injection, micronaut

I'm testing a Micronaut class that has a bean injected into it. In my test I provide a `@MockBean` class to override it. However, it seems Micronaut still injects the real dependency.

```
@MicronautTest
public class ClassUnderTestTest {

    @Inject ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void test() {

    }

    @MockBean
    Dependency dependency() {
        return mock(Dependency.class);
    }

}
```

I uploaded a minimum repro to Github: https://github.com/crummy/micronaut-test-dependencies . The real dependency throws an exception, and the test does too. I would not have expected this to happen because of my `@MockBean`.

If I change the annotation to be `@MockBean(Dependency.class)` then I get this error: `Message: No bean of type [di.failure.example.Dependency] exists`. This seems even more confusing to me - now it doesn't resolve my real or my mock dependency?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Injecting mock bean with `@MockBean` annotation works if your dependency in `ClassUnderTest` is represented by interface. Let's say `Dependency` is a simple interface like:

```
package di.failure.example;

public interface Dependency {
    void run();
}
```

Your application may provide an implementation for this interface called `DependencyImpl`:

```
package di.failure.example;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class DependencyImpl implements Dependency {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException("I don't want this to load!");
    }
}
```

Now, for test purpose you can define a mock that replaces `DependencyImpl`:

```
package di.failure.example;

import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest;
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MockBean;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

@MicronautTest
public class ClassUnderTestTest {

    @Inject
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        classUnderTest.run();
    }

    @MockBean(DependencyImpl.class)
    public Dependency dependency() {
        return mock(Dependency.class);
    }

}
```

This test executes and the mock returned by `dependency()` method is used in place  of `DependencyImpl`.

### Using `@Replaces` annotation

As [Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2138/sergio-del-amo) mentioned in the comments section you can replace class based bean dependency using [`@Replaces`](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#replaces) annotation. Consider following example:

```
package di.failure.example;

import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Replaces;
import io.micronaut.test.annotation.MicronautTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@MicronautTest
public class ClassUnderTestTest {

    @Inject
    ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        classUnderTest.run();
    }

    @Replaces(Dependency.class)
    @Singleton
    public static class MockDependency extends Dependency {

        public MockDependency() {
            System.out.println("MockDependency.<init>");
        }

        @Override
        void run() {
            System.out.println("Does not throw any exception...");
        }
    }
}
```

In this example we have defined a class `MockDependency` and we instruct Micronaut's DI mechanism to replace `Dependency` bean with `MockDependency`. However, there is one important thing we need to remember about - because our `MockDependency` extends `Dependency` class, parent construct gets invoked. The example you have shown in the question won't work in this case, because `Dependency.<init>` throws `RuntimeException` and the test fails. In this modified example I have used class like this one:

```
package di.failure.example;

import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class Dependency {

    public Dependency() {
        System.out.println("Dependency.<init>");
    }

    void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException("I don't want this to load!");
    }
}
```

When I run the test it passes and I see following console output:

```
Dependency.<init>
MockDependency.<init>
Does not throw any exception...
```

The main difference comparing to `@MockBean` is that in case of `@Replaces` you are using a concrete class object. As a workaround (if we really need a Mockito mock object) is to create a mock internally and delegate calls to this object, something like this:

```
@Replaces(Dependency.class)
@Singleton
public class MockDependency extends Dependency {

    private final Dependency delegate;

    public MockDependency() {
        this.delegate = mock(Dependency.class);
    }

    @Override
    void run() {
        delegate.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, that's a shame (I prefer to avoid interfaces unless I have a practical need for them.) But I guess this is one.

Comment: If you need to replace a class you can always create a bean in the test classpath and use @Replaces

Comment: Thanks @SergiodelAmo for the valuable input! I have updated the answer with `@Replaces` annotation use case.

Comment: What is I want to override a property value, not a whole bean? Typical examples are in-memory databases.

Comment: "What is I want to override a property value, not a whole bean?" - you can do that with environment specific config files like `src/main/resources/application-test.yml`.  Tests marked with `@MicronautTest` can also provide their own config values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the case - controller `MyController` with service `MyService`.
`@MockBean(MyServiceImpl.class)` did't mock injected service.
`when(myService.doSomething()).thenReturn...` immediately called real method.
I fixed mocking issue with giving `MyService`-bean a name and passing this name to `@MockBean(name = )`

controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
   private MyService myService;
...
}
```

factory:

```
@Factory
public class MyFactory {

   @Named("myService") // Named just because @MockBean didn't work without it
   @Context
   public MyService myService() {
      return new MyServiceImpl();
   }
}
```

test:

```
@MicronautTest
class MyControllerTest {
  
   @Inject
   MyService myService;

   @Inject
   @Client("/")
   @HttpClient client;


   @MockBean(named = "myService")
   MyService mockMyService() {
      return mock(MyService.class);
   }


   @Test
   void test() {
      when(myService.doSomething()).thenReturn(genDto()); 
      ...
   }
}
```

Details:
micronaut-test-junit5 `3.1.1`
junit-jupiter-api  `5.6.2`